# Retrying connect to server: Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Tags: docker, hadoop, weave

I have three physical nodes. In each node I enter to docker with this command.

```
   docker run -v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh --privileged 
   -p 5050:5050 -p 5051:5051 -p 5052:5052 -p 2181:2181 -p 8089:8081 
   -p 6123:6123 -p 8084:8080 -p 50090:50090 -p 50070:50070 
   -p 9000:9000 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 -p 4041:4040 -p 8020:8020 
   -p 8485:8485 -p 7078:7077 -p 52222:22 -e WEAVE_CIDR=10.32.0.3/12 
   -e MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=5mins 
   -e LIBPROCESS_IP=10.32.0.3 
   -e MESOS_RESOURCES=ports*:[11000-11999] 
   -ti hadoop_marathon_mesos_flink_2 /bin/bash
```

I configure hadoop like this:
**Core-site.xml** :

```
 <configuration>
   <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
   </property>
 </configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**:

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
      <value>
   qjournal://10.32.0.1:8485;10.32.0.2:8485;10.32.0.3:8485/mycluster
      </value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
      <value>/tmp/hadoop/dfs/jn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
      <value>mycluster</value>
      <description>Logical name for this new 
      nameservice</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>
      <value>nn1,nn2</value>
      <description>Unique identifiers for each NameNode in the 
      nameservice</description>
    </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
       <value>10.32.0.1:8020</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
       <value>10.32.0.2:8020</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
       <value>10.32.0.1:50070</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
       <value>10.32.0.2:50070</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
       <value>
           org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.
           ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider
       </value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
       <value>shell(/bin/true)</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.
       ip-hostname-check</name>
       <value>false</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
       <value>true</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
       <value>10.32.0.1:2181,10.32.0.2:2181,10.32.0.3:2181</value>
     </property>
   </configuration>
```

The problem is when I format **namenode**:

```
   hadoop namenode -format
```

It cannot format **namenode**. I receive this error:

> 2019-05-06 06:35:09,969 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 10.32.0.2/10.32.0.2:8485. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>
> 2019-05-06 06:35:09,969 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 10.32.0.3/10.32.0.3:8485. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>
> 2019-05-06 06:35:09,987 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting. 1 exceptions thrown:
>
> 10.32.0.1:8485: Call From 50c5244de4cd/10.32.0.1 to 50c5244de4cd:8485 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I have already published ports which are required in Hadoop, but still I receive **connection refused**.

Would someone please tell me what problem the configuration has?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved it was because of zookeeper configuration in **core-site.xml**. I explain details in high available hadoop configuration in following:
**hdfs-site.xml**:

```
<property>
     <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
     <value>mycluster</value>
     <description>Logical name for this new nameservice</description>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>
     <value>nn1,nn2</value>
     <description>Unique identifiers for each NameNode in 
      the nameservice</description>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
     <value>10.32.0.2:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
     <value>10.32.0.2:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.
     server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
     <value>
      qjournal://10.32.0.1:8485;10.32.0.2:8485;10.32.0.3:8485/mycluster
     </value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.permissions.enable</name>
     <value> false </value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
    <value>sshfence</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
    <value>/home/hdfs/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.connect-timeout</name>
    <value>30000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
    <value>hdfs</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

**core-site.xml** (for example in node "10.32.0.1"):

```
 <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:2181,10.32.0.2:2181,10.32.0.3:2181</value>
 </property>
```

Zookeeper configuration for example in "10.32.0.1" is :

```
  server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
  server.2=10.32.0.2:2888:3888
  server.3=10.32.0.3:2888:3888
```

Also, I made **myid** file in **/var/lib/zookeeper/data** with ID of that node.
First, delete all bellow folders:

```
  rm -rf /tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode
  rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
  rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
  rm -rf /opt/hadoop/logs/*
```

Then, make these folders:

```
  mkdir /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
  mkdir /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
```

After that, give correct permission to those folders:

```
  chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
  chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
  chown -R root /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
  chown -R root /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
  chmod 777 /tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode
  chown -R root /tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode
```

Now you can follow this stage to format those folders. 
The most important things is how to format these three nodes. You must follow these stages:
1. Stop the Hdfs service
2. Start only the journal nodes (as they will need to be made aware of the formatting)

```
   /opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs --daemon start journalnode
```

3. On the first namenode (as user hdfs or root)

   hadoop namenode -format
4. On the journalnodes:

   hdfs namenode -initializeSharedEdits -force
5. Restart Zookeeper:

   /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkServer.sh restart
6. Format Zookeeper :

   ```
   hdfs zkfc -formatZK -force (to force zookeeper to reinitialise)
   ```
7. restart that first namenode:

   ```
   /opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs --daemon start namenode
   ```
8. On the second namenode:

   ```
   hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby -force ​(force synch with first namenode)
   ```
9. On every datanode clear the data directory:

   ```
   hadoop datanode -format
   ```
10. Restart the HDFS service:

    ```
    /opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
    ```

By the way, I have three nodes, two namenodes and one datanode.
You can check hadoop log in **/opt/hadoop/logs/**.